# How to suppress Package Control Messages popup in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Ok, I've suffered long enough:  I can't stand the Package Control Messages tab that pops up and grabs focus when I open ST3.  You know, the one that looks like

```
Package Control Messages
========================

Package Control:
---------------

  Version 3.0 Release Notes
...
```

Is there a way to suppress this popup?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17389) answer your question ?

Comment: The PyV8 folder suggestion didn't help - I don't have that folder.  So the other solution seems like a manual uninstall and reinstall? Grrr... I don't want the spam *at all, ever*...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So, the only (hackish) way so far I've found to do this is to comment out a line in the Package Control package... hopefully someone responds with a better answer than this.

### Better Way

1. Install PackageResourceViewer from Package Control
2. `Open Resource` via PackageResourceViewer -> Select `Package Control`
3. Select `package_control/package_manager.py` to edit
4. Comment out line `self.print_messages(package_name, package_dir, is_upgrade, old_version, new_version)` by putting a hash `#` in the front
5. Save file.

### Clunky Way

1. Locate `Package Control.sublime-package` (on my machine [Linux] it's in ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages) (on Win7 it's in c:\Users[YOUR_NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages)
2. Make a copy of this package in case you bork this process
3. Unzip the package into a directory of your choosing (a .sublime-package is just a zipped archive)
4. Open `./package_control/package_manager.py` (notice it's a subfolder inside)
5. Comment out line `self.print_messages(package_name, package_dir, is_upgrade, old_version, new_version)` by putting a hash `#` in the front
6. Zip all files
7. Rename new zip as `Package Control.sublime-package`
8. Overwrite old package with your new package

Answer (score 2):

The grabbing focus was annoying me as well. I got rid of it by disabling the auto-upgrade option of Package Control:

1. Open `Preferences: Package Control Settings - User`
2. Add the item `"auto_upgrade": false`

Note, you'll need to upgrade manually from now on by running `Package Control: Upgrade Package`